# apt-get update does not work

Tags: apt, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7, glibc

I have just installed Ubuntu for the second time (separate downloads) onto my nexus 7. Both the times I could not use apt-get upgrade and thus could not install any applications.

Upon the second installation I turned the terminal mode on while setup was happening and noticed that Glibc had not set up properly for some reason both the times (could this be the problem??).

i have tried all the possible things i could find off other questions. some other things i can think would be important are-

1. during both the downloads the internet connection was lost in the middle and then the download was recovered
2. i have just attached a new switch into my connection, this has been giving me some DSL problems on my PC but not on WIFI so i dont think this is the cause
3. i can browse webpages and do virtaully anthing related to the internet on ubuntu but when i try to send an error report or a bug report the the update fails due to no internet connectivity! also when i try to select the best server it gives the same error
4. ping to 8.8.8.8 gives back a 0% loss
5. for some reason when i try to select my mirror and chose the regional one (in.ubuntu.archive.com/ubuntu) it selects that mirror but upon reboot resets to the main one. this happens even if i change it in the sources.list
6. upon installation of the latest 13.04 on my nexus 7, i am asked to upgrade to the more stable 13.10 but i am not able to do this in termianl since it says i have no internet connectivity and when i do it through the update manager, the confirmation window is too big for my screen and i cannot select accept so i am still using the 13.04
7. apart from the Glibc error displayed on setup i do not beleive there was any other error during installation. i used the Multirom instructions step by step.
8. the error messages vary everytime from, something wicked has happened to some files failed to install and sometimes both

i have been trying to test this on my old nexus 7 as a test before putting it on my new one, but dont think that i will unless this problem is solved.
any help is appreaciated! :)

please tell me if you want to see my `sources.list`, `resolv.conf` or installation logs

I have removed `http://` so it doesn't show links

```
root@pranay-finaltest:/home/pranay# apt-get update
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring Release
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_IN
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/source/Sources  404  Not
Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/source/Sources  404
Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-armhf/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-armhf/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones
used instead.
root@pranay-finaltest:/home/pranay# gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
root@pranay-finaltest:/home/pranay# apt-get update
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring-security Release.gpg
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring Release
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring-security Release
Err ports.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release.gpg
  Something wicked happened resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com:http' (-11 - System
error)
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Ign ports.ubuntu.com raring-security Release.gpg
Ign ports.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Ign ports.ubuntu.com raring-security Release
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_IN
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
24% [Waiting for headers]^C
root@pranay-finaltest:/home/pranay# gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
root@pranay-finaltest:/home/pranay# apt-get update
Ign ports.ubuntu.com raring-security Release.gpg
Ign ports.ubuntu.com raring-security Release
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release.gpg
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring-security Release.gpg
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring Release
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring-security Release
Err ports.ubuntu.com raring-security/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Err ports.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Err ports.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Err ports.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]
Ign ports.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en_IN
Ign ports.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en
Ign ports.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign ports.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign ports.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign ports.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign ports.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign ports.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_IN
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en_IN
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err archive.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
W: Failed to fetch
ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/raring-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]

W: Failed to fetch
ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/raring-security/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]

W: Failed to fetch
ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/raring-security/universe/binary-armhf/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]

W: Failed to fetch
ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/raring-security/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/source/Sources  404  Not
Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/source/Sources  404
Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-armhf/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-armhf/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/main/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/restricted/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/universe/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/multiverse/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/universe/binary-armhf/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/restricted/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/multiverse/source/Sources
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones
used instead.
```

Comment: what message do you get in a terminal when run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` ?

Comment: If you're using a Nexus 7, you might not be using the `i386` or `amd64` architecture, in which case you should be using `http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/`. In addition, navigating to `in.ubuntu.archive.com/ubuntu` gives a 500 server error. It could be the mirror is down.

Comment: @saiarcot I'll look into the i386 and the amd64 architecture however the problem is not them mirror as I have tried from both main server and the Indian one. Both give the same error

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I have already written in the question. At first I get the some files failed to fetch error and after following some other solutions like deleting lock and changing resolve.conf to googles DNS I have started getting the something wicked happened error

Comment: @saiarcot895 I have checked and my port is already set to ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/

Comment: post the exact commands you ran and the error message please.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen done, just tell me if you want me to post resolve.conf or sources.list too

Comment: your version of ubuntu (13.04) IS BEYOND END OF LIFE. I suggest yuo do a fresh install of 14.04 or see the link Jorge gave you

Comment: why are you using resolvconf to change dns? if you read the file it states that the file will be overwritten. 13.04 uses network-manager if you did not uninstall it. Go into the network-manager and select to edit connections and from there choose ipv4 and you should be able to figure out how to set DNS from there.

Comment: @mchid I have done it with that as well, and the resolve.conf doesn't get overwritten if you have root access

Comment: **INCORRECTLY CLOSED AS DUPLICATE:** This is NOT a **past end-of-life** issue with Raring (13.04), but rather an unsupported *older* version of Ubuntu Touch (or earlier variant). The first question to ask is: ***Is this a 'Nexus 7' or 'Nexus 7 (2013)' device?*** or ***Why have you not installed a later BETA version?***

Comment: @david6 then why did the OP accept the answer?

Comment: @david6 no it is past end-of-life. I have done this on both devices 2013 and original and this works. Also I haven't installed a BETA version because this is the most compatible with the nexus range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried some of the ip addresses on my browser and sure enough looking at the list I noticed . . . These are all for "**updates**" and **"security"** updates which are no longer provided because 13.04 is EOL - LOL.

There are no updates for this version of Ubuntu anymore. You must use a newer version of Ubuntu or remove the update & security URLs from /etc/apt/sources.list which I do not recommend.

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring = 404 not found

however

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise = connection

Comment: *I don't think this is a valid answer.* The question is about a **Nexus 7** device, and running **Ubuntu** on it.

Comment: @david6 no, the question was about running apt-get on an unsupported version of ubuntu.

Comment: @david to answer YOUR QUESTION see here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes#Ubuntu_Touch there is one supported and one Nexus 7, that is **no longer supported**, listed. Instructions for the supported version are here http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/

Comment: Unless it is a **Nexus 7 (2013)**. *And, I was well aware of your answer.* I currently have three 'Nexus 7 (2013)' devices, running **Ubuntu Touch BETA** or **Android 'L' (5.x BETA).**

Comment: @david6 I have checked and this does work, its a correct answer. I have used every possible feature after this, no bugs or issues