# Installing pkgs via Muon on raring 13.04

Tags: software-installation

on a new partition with kubuntu 13.04 when i try to install any new pkgs 
(i tried wine , qtoctave ) i get a unable to access from 
here are a few examples 
http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/source/Sources 404 Not Found etc...
have these pkgs moved elsewhere?

previously i had wine 1.4 installed properly and operational 
with muon i cannot complete the update

any hints would be welcome
thanks 
Gio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update to a supported version of Ubuntu. 13.04 has been out of support (EOL) for like 9 months now. When you update to 14.04, or downgrade to 12.04 the app will work and you will no longer receive the 404 error. See here [apt-get update does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499986/apt-get-update-does-not-work/500142#500142)

And these test URLs show this to be true

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring = 404

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise = connection

Comment: 14.10 is a development version, and isn't recommended for general usage.

Comment: @saiarcot895 fixed